# Wireguard: How do I verify web traffic & would it be considered encrypted?

Tags: encryption, wireguard

I setup a connection between my Windows PC & a VitualBox Debian Server running WireGuard using [this](https://shebangthedolphins.net/vpn_wireguard_bullseye.html) walkthrough. The connection appears to be working because the Windows WireGuard Client GUI shows that data is being transferred and I can see packets on the Debian server using tcpdump (only on my network cards interface (enp0s3, not wg0).

Questions

1. I would have assumed that the tcpdump would show info data transfer through wg0 since that is what the walkthrough determines as the interface that i set up. Am i misunderstanding something?
2. My goal for this was to encrypt my web traffic. As a result of this connection, would my web traffic in fact be encrypted? If so, is there a way to verify this?

Comment: I think this is better to be asked superuser or Unix...

Comment: Thanks for migrating this

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following command on your Debian server (where `enp0s3` is your Ethernet interface and `51820` is your WireGuard listen port):

```
sudo tcpdump -i enp0s3 'tcp port 51820'
```

The traffic you see is the encrypted traffic incoming or outgoing through your WireGuard tunnel.

And if you run the following command (where `wg0` is your WireGuard interface):

```
sudo tcpdump -i wg0
```

The traffic you see is the *decrypted* traffic after it comes out of or before it goes into your encrypted WireGuard tunnel.

So if you run one of the above tcpdump commands on your Debian server, and while that's running, you visit a web site in your browser on your Windows PC, and you see some output from tcpdump, that means the traffic between your Windows PC and Debian server was encrypted. Note that WireGuard only encrypts traffic *between your Windows PC and Debian server* -- on the server it's decrypted, and sent on in the clear to the web site.

But if your end goal is anonymous web browsing (ie prevent your ISP from tracking what sites you visit), I would suggest just checking with one of the various "vpn leak test" sites (like https://dnsleaktest.com/ et al) -- if it shows your Debian server IP address rather than your home address, that means your web traffic is being encrypted and sent between your Windows PC and Debian server through WireGuard.